# Update only if all columns are present - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the below mentioned table structure for `Animal` table:

```
AnimalId | AnimalName | SelectAnimal
1        | Cat        | NULL
2        | Dog        | NULL
3        | Sheep      | NULL
4        | Cow        | NULL
```

`AnimalFeature` table:

```
Animal Id | Feature | Present 
1         | Teeth   | Y      
1         | Milk    | Y
1         | Tail    | Y
2         | Teeth   | Y
3         | MILK    | Y
4         | Teeth   | Y
4         | MILK    | N
4         | Tail    | Y
```

and I'm generating a comma-separated list for present column using the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A1.AnimalId,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ltrim(rtrim(A2.Present))
           FROM Animal AS A2
           WHERE A1.AnimalId = A2.AnimalId
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') As ConcatValue 
FROM    
    Animal as A1 
GROUP BY 
    AnimalId;
```

The requirement is to update the animal master table only if all the features are present.

If first two features are yes, then `selectanimal` column will have yes else no 
if not all features are present , those record needs to be ignored.

The final output should be like

```
1   CAT    Y 
2   DOG    NULL
3   SHEEP  NULL 
4   COW    N
```

Could you please give Any pointers or help on how to accomplish this?

Comment: No need to do `SELECT DISTINCT` since your `GROUP BY` returns no duplicates! (Somewhat similar functionality, aggregate functions is the main difference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should do what you need

```
WITH AF AS (
SELECT AnimalId,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
                                 WHEN Present = 'Y' AND Feature IN ('Teeth', 'Milk' 
                                 THEN Feature 
                                 END) >= 2 
            THEN 'Y' 
            ELSE 'N' 
            END AS SelectAnimal         
FROM AnimalFeature
WHERE Feature IN ('Teeth', 'Milk', 'Tail')
GROUP BY AnimalId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Feature) = 3
)
UPDATE A
SET A.SelectAnimal = AF.SelectAnimal
FROM Animal A JOIN AF ON A.AnimalId = AF.AnimalId
```